# Facebook for HTC Sense not working

Tags: htc-sense, facebook

Somehow, Facebook for HTC Sense has disappear from my HTC Vivid.

In `/system/app` I've found `HtcFacebook` which is  `com.htc.socialnetwork.facebook`. When I try to install it errors with **Application not installed**.

I've tried to find this package on the Internet to install it, but could't find it anywhere.

How can I get the HTC Facebook back onto the device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many failed tries to reactivate the HTC Facebook, I've decided to **reset to factory defaults**. This fixed the issue. Now **Facebook for HTC** is working fine.